# Can you help me with Django's URL regex?

Tags: python, regex, django

Currently, one of my urls is not working properly because I can't match it. I have the following entry in my urls.py

```
url(r'no_inventariado/nuevo/(?P<nombre>\S+)/(?P<serie>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/(?P<extension>\d{4})', 'inventario.views.nuevo_resguardo', name='nuevo_resguardo'),$
```

The problem seems to be in `<nombre>`. The url I'm using contains uppercase, lowercase and spaces in the `<nombre>` spot.

Ex.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/inventario/no_inventariado/nuevo/LUIS%20%20RICARDO%20DAVID%20P/XXXBX7399F11/7070/
```

How could I fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you have pasted for `url(...)` seems to be messed up. I'm not sure which part is the regex and which part isn't. Does the regex end at `(?P<extension>\d{4})>`? There are spaces after that.

Comment: @alan It seems it got messed up when I pasted it. Thanks for noticing, fixed!

Comment: Is there really a `>` at the end of the regex?

Comment: @alan nope.. that was vim, fixed it again, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you now allow `\S+`, means any non whitespace character, and you now want to add space then use `.+?`

```
url(r'no_inventariado/nuevo/(?P<nombre>.+?)/(?P<serie>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/(?P<extension>\d{4})>     'inventario.views.nuevo_resguardo', name='nuevo_resguardo'),$
```

The `+?` to have a non greedy match, means `.+?` will match every character till the next slash.

Comment: I'm planning on having special characters like á, so this works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`\S` should match all non-whitespace characters, but the `%20`s in your example are encoded spaces. I can't say for sure, but I'm guessing the whitespace is getting decoded before the GET request reaches the url handler. You can confirm this by testing with a name without spaces on it.

If this is the problem you can work around it by using a capture group like `(?P<nombre>[^/]+)` instead ("everything that is not a forward slash").

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple test and it works on my machine:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request, nombre):
    return HttpResponse('Hello: '+nombre)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<nombre>[a-zA-Z\s]*)/$', hello),
)
```

But it doesn't work with \S

Comment: At the moment the regex allows `\S` ==> a non whitespace character and `%` is a non whitespace character.

Comment: I've changed my answer, please check it.

Comment: This works alright, but since I'm planning on using special characters like á, I'm gonna use @stema's answer. Thanks!